# SharpDevelop- Cannot find embedded resource at design time

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, embedded-resource, sharpdevelop

In my Windows Forms application, I add an image as a resource (Embedded) which I'm trying to use as a background image for a control.

When I click on the Properties of the control and the **Select Resource**  pops up , the **Project Resource** tab/option is empty. Shouldn't it contain the image I've added as a resource?

When I use the **Local Resource** and choose it from the drive, it gets attached to the control ok but when I re-open the project another time, the image is missing hence the control has no background image property

The resource is added in the manifest as

```
<data name="background" type="System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
    <value>
...
    <\value>
```

but does not show up in the **Project Resource** tab

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an image to your project and settings its **Build Action** to **EmbeddedResource** will not make it available to add to your Windows Form via a **Project Resource**. The Windows Forms designer needs the image inside a resource file (.resx) in order to be able to access use it as a Project Resource. To do this you can add a new **Empty resource file** to your project.

[image: Empty resource file template]

Then you can add your image to the resource by opening the resource file into the editor, right clicking, selecting **Add Files**, and finally selecting the image. In the screenshot below I have added an image already.

[image: Image in Resources.resx file]

Then your image should be available when changing a background for a control.

[image: Forms designer - selecting image in project resource]

Now I am unable to reproduce the problem where an image added as a Local Resource going missing. I am using SharpDevelop 4.4.1 and have created a Windows Forms application targeting .NET 4.5. The image is always available even after closing and re-opening the project or SharpDevelop itself.